# Include white spaces while using CUT command

Tags: linux, shell, filter, cut

I tried to extract 11 characters (default) enclosed with in tag from a file using cut command. If the characters comprises a double space, the cut command gives the output with a single spacing.

The file I am working on looks like :

```html
blablaFirst  lastblabla
```

The command I have used is :

```html
cut -c7-18 file.txt
```

The non desired result is (only **one space** instead of **two** between **first** and **last**) :

```html
First last
```

Here is the main code :

```html
c_line="file.txt"
targetfile="result.txt"
var1=0
while read c_line
do
var1=`grep -c "IIT   Chennai" $c_line`
echo $var1 >> $targetfile
if [ $var1 -ge 1 ]
then
val=`cut -c7-18 $c_line`
echo $var >> $targetfile

fi
done<${c_line}
```

I rather keep using cut

do you know what is the problem with cut ?

Comment: Maybe you have a tab there not spaces? I tried it with spaces and it works correctly (preserving spaces): `First  lastb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this part of your script is a typo:

```
val=`cut -c7-18 $c_line`
echo $var >> $targetfile
#       ^ should be $val
```

So the problem is that you're using `$val`, when you should be using `"$val"`.

When you expand a variable without quotes, word-splitting occurs, so `echo` sees two arguments:

```
echo 'First' 'last'
```

These arguments are printed, separated by a single space.